# DB4O performance retrieving a large number of objects

Tags: java, db4o

I'm interesting in using DB4O to store the training data for a learning algorithm.  This will consist of (potentially) hundreds of millions of objects.  Each object is on average 2k in size based on my benchmarking.

The training algorithm needs to iterate over the entire set of objects repeatedly (perhaps 10 times).  It doesn't care what order the objects are in.

My question is this:  When I retrieve a very large set of objects from DB4O, are they all loaded into memory, or are they pulled off disk as needed?

Clearly, pulling hundreds of millions of 2k objects into memory won't be practical on the type of servers I'm working with (they hvae about 19GB of RAM).

Is Db4o a wise choice here?

Comment: Two things -- 1. are the objects each really 2k, or is there a natural opportunity to normalize the data? Remember that DB4O is an object database so take advantage of rich object models. 2 I would do an experiment about what is retained in memory. I know that by default it keeps objects in memory, but I don't know if it will trim it down to a shell of the object if it is unmodified and there is need for more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db4o [activation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/activation.htm) mechanism allows you to control which object are loaded into memory. For complex object graphs you probably should us [transparent activation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/transparent_persistence.htm), where db4o loads an object into memory as soon as it is used. 
However db4o doesn't explicit remove object from memory. It just keeps a weak reference to all loaded objects. If a object is reachable, it will stay there (just like any other object). Optionally you can explicitly deactivate an object.

I just want to add a few notes to the scalability of db4o. db4o was built for embedding in application and devices. It was never built for large datasets. Therefore it has its limitations.

- It is internally single-threaded. Most db4o operation block all other db4o operations.
- It can only deal with relatively small databases. By default a database can only be 2GB. You can [increase it up to](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/troubleshoot/increasing_the_maximum_database_file_size.htm) 127 GB. However I think db4o operates well in the 2-16 GB range. Afterwards the database is probably to large for it. Anyway, hundreds of millions of 2K objects is way to large database. (100Mio 2K obj => 200GB)

Therefore you probably should look at larger object databases, like [VOD](http://www.versant.com/index.aspx). Or maybe a graph database like [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) is also a good choise for your problem?